# Replacing one string with another string using Regex in Python: Error: re.error: bad escape \w at position 0

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace occurrences of; for example 'word one' with 'word_one'. Replacing the whitespace with a '_'.

Here is my code:

```
labels_ls = ['word <= 0.01', 'word_two <= 0.23', 'word three <= 0.01']

regex_whitespace = r'\w+\s+\w+\b'
new_regex = r'\w+\_+\w+\b'
pattern = re.compile(regex_whitespace) # this I just added after reviewing other related questions

# Loop through labels_ls to find any ngrams whitespace separated labels (i.e gilt maximal)

for i in labels_ls:
    if re.match(regex_whitespace, i):
        # replace the whitespace with a '_' to form gilt*maximal
        new_string = re.sub(pattern, new_regex, i)
        print('new string: ', new_string)
```

I have tested my regex here https://pythex.org, and it works as required, however when I run this code I get the following error:

re.error: bad escape \w at position 0

I have looked at all the related answered questions:

[how to fix - error: bad escape \u at position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54330673/how-to-fix-error-bad-escape-u-at-position-0)

and

[Regex: Replace one pattern with another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950559/regex-replace-one-pattern-with-another)

I have tried removing the r before the regex as mentioned in the above question however it still doesn't work.

I also tried using compile() but this also didn't fix the problem

```
labels_ls = ['internal_punctuation <= 0.042', 'darf <= 0.717', 'formal_global_yes <= 0.5', 'wert <= 0.272', 'signal <= 0.5', 'Flesch_Index <= 0.813', 'zulass <= 0.379', 'polarity <= 0.713', 'Nb_of_auxiliary <= 0.071', 'gini = 0.0', 'polarity <= 0.375', 'gini = 0.0', 'Nb_of_verbs <= 0.094', 'weakwords_nb <= 0.143', 'passive_global_yes <= 0.5', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'Nb_of_verbs <= 0.094', 'passive_global_yes <= 0.5', 'WPS <= 0.062', 'measurement_values_no <= 0.5', 'gini = 0.0', 'SPW <= 0.575', 'weird_words <= 0.042', 'weakwords_nb <= 0.036', 'SPW <= 0.272', 'gini = 0.0', 'words_nb <= 0.033', 'gini = 0.5', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'Flesch_Index <= 0.774', 'SPW <= 0.331', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'Comp_conj <= 0.375', 'SPW <= 0.111', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'Sub_Conj <= 0.25', 'weird_words <= 0.208', 'zsdf <= 0.5', 'signal <= 0.297', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'words_nb <= 0.164', 'Aux_Start_no <= 0.5', 'gini = 0.0', 'Nb_of_Umsetzbarkeit_conj <= 0.167', 'werden <= 0.125', 'darf <= 0.297', 'polarity <= 0.925', 'SPW <= 0.376', 'WPS <= 0.11', 'numerical_values <= 0.091', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'WPS <= 0.11', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'polarity <= 0.25', 'gini = 0.0', 'Flesch_Index <= 0.663', 'words_nb <= 0.033', 'SPW <= 0.475', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'Comp_conj <= 0.125', 'gini = 0.56', 'gini = 0.0', 'Flesch_Index <= 0.75', 'gini = 0.444', 'gini = 0.0', 'Aux_Start_yes <= 0.5', 'darf <= 0.241', 'Nb_of_verbs <= 0.156', 'gini = 0.0', 'SPW <= 0.246', 'polarity <= 0.675', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'Sub_Conj <= 0.25', 'numerical_values <= 0.227', 'funktion <= 0.348', 'internal_punctuation <= 0.458', 'polarity <= 0.375', 'gini = 0.0', 'Nb_of_verbs <= 0.031', 'gini = 0.0', 'Flesch_Index <= 0.409', 'gini = 0.0', 'numerical_values <= 0.136', 'WPS <= 0.065', 'darf <= 0.359', 'Nb_of_Umsetzbarkeit_conj <= 0.167', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'formal_global_no <= 0.5', 'WPS <= 0.164', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'gilt randbeding <= 0.181', 'fahrzeug <= 0.352', 'gini = 0.0', 'zulass <= 0.082', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'fur <= 0.194', 'weakwords_nb <= 0.321', 'gini = 0.444', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'Nb_of_Umsetzbarkeit_conj <= 0.167', 'Nb_of_verbs <= 0.344', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0', 'words_nb <= 0.178', 'gini = 0.0', 'words_nb <= 0.224', 'gini = 0.0', 'gini = 0.0']
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of `labels_ls`? Also, `\w` matches underscores. What exact chars do you need to match with your regex?

Comment: Is regex a requirement? I believe ```str.replace()``` will make life a lot easier for that job.

Comment: Comment out the re.sub() line and try it. Is that the line the error is on ? You may need to double escape the escapes : `r'\\w+\\_+\\w+\\b'` since this is the replacement string.

Comment: Why do you replace with a regex pattern?

Comment: @sln yes that is the line which causes the error. But I need a way of replacing the whitespace with a _

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I guess I thought that would be the best way, is there a better way?

Comment: `new_string = re.sub(r"\s", "_", i)`

Comment: @accdias I tried using str.replace initially but I couldn't manage to make it work, I tried i.replace(" ", "_") but this doesn't work, how can I use str.replace() in this instance?

Comment: @codiearcher, what do you mean by it doesn't work? What was the error?

Comment: Or, if it really bother's you that underscore should only be between words:  `new_string = re.sub(r"(?<\w)\s+(?=\w)", "_", i)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use

```
regex_whitespace = r'(\w+)\s+(\w+)\b'
```

and then later:

```
new_string = re.sub(pattern, r'\1_\2', i)
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/upA46g).

The point is that you need to capture the word chars matched with the first regex into [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and then use [backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) to the matched group values. The `new_regex = r'\w+\_+\w+\b'` is redundant as you cannot have a regex pattern as a replacement, replacement patterns can only contain backreferences and escaped sequences (the literal backslash must be escaped there).

Comment: I replaced the code with what you wrote and I'm not sure why but I get the following error: raise s.error ("invalid group reference %d" % index, pos)
re.error: invalid group reference 1 at position 1.

Comment: @codiearcher Please copy/paste from [here](https://ideone.com/upA46g). If you have other issues, just share a Python code snippet via ideone. I believe you forgot to add capturing groups.

Comment: I guess the problem is with my actual list (I just made a dummy list) which appears to not be accepting the regex. I will add the original data from labels_ls above. What is catering groups? I will look at ideone. Thanks

Comment: See https://ideone.com/xYaiA0, all works as expected. The groups are *capturing*, not *catering*.